# Как создать DataFrame из многомерных списков?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Есть несколько массивов типа `Series`, есть список индексов для будущего DataFrame, и есть список названий столбцов и название столбца для индексов.

Наглядный пример:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
indexes = [00:00, 00:01, 00:02, 00:03, 00:04]
cols = ['values1', 'values2', 'values3']
indexes_name = "Time"
```

Как это можно преобразовать в DataFrame:

```
Time   values1   values2   values3
00:00     1         6         11
00:01     2         7         12
00:02     3         8         13 
00:03     4         9         14
00:03     5         10        15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Data).T.set_index(indexes)
df.columns = cols
df = df.rename_axis(indexes_name)
```